# Can I delete an element from an HDF5 dataset?

Tags: python, hdf5

I would like to delete an element from an HDF5 dataset in Python. Below I have my example code

**DeleteHDF5Dataset.py**

```
# This code works, which deletes an HDF5 dataset from an HDF5 file

file_name = os.path.join('myfilepath', 'myfilename.hdf5')
f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r+')
f.__delitem__('Log list')
```

However, this is not what I want to do. 'mydatatset' is an HDF5 dataset that has several elements, and I would like to delete one or more of the elements individually, for example

**DeleteHDF5DatasetElement.py**

```
# This code does not work, but I would like to achieve what it's trying to do

file_name = os.path.join('myfilepath', 'myfilename.hdf5')
f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r+')

print(f['Log list'][3]) # prints the correct dataset element

f.__delitem__('Log list')[3]  # I want to delete element 3 of this HDF5 dataset
```

The best solution I can come up with is to create a temporary dataset, loop through the original dataset, and only add the entries I want to keep to the temp dataset, and then replace the old dataset with the new one. But this seems pretty clunky. Does anybody have a clean solution to do this? It seems like there should be a simple way to just delete an element.

Thanks, and sorry if any of my terminology is incorrect.

Comment: What does your `mydataset` dataset look like? Is it a `float` array, or something else? *In general*, HDF5 is not optimal for deleting data, since disk space is not freed by default.

Comment: It's a tuple in the current case I'm working with

Comment: HDF5 files don't have a concept of `tuple`. HDF5 is a cross-platform data format written in C. What do you see when you print `f['Log list'][3]` ?

Comment: ('string_example',)

Comment: Yeah maybe it's not a tuple, but it sure looks like some odd form of an array that resembles a tuple

Comment: What about `f['Log list'].shape` / `f['Log list'].size` / `f['Log list'].dtype` - this might help understand your data better.

Comment: printing f['Log list'][3][0] gives me 'string_example'

Comment: print(f['Log list'][3].dtype ---> [('channel_name'), 'O']

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will probably just loop through it as I originally proposed because it appears this functionality isn't there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an array of strings. It's not the [recommended way](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html#compatibility) of storing strings in HDF5, but let's assume you have no choice on how data is stored.

HDF5 *prefers* you to keep your array size fixed. Operations such as deleting arbitrary elements are expensive. In addition, with HDF5, space is not automatically freed when you delete data.

After all this, if you still want to remove data in your specified format, you can try simply extracting an array, deleting an element, then reassigning to your dataset:

```
arr = f['Log list'][:]  # extract to numpy array
res = np.delete(arr, 1)  # delete element with index 1, i.e. second element
f.__delitem__('Log list')  # delete existing dataset
f['Log list'] = res  # reassign to dataset
```

Comment: This would be exactly what I want, except when I run this, I get an error on the final line, that says "Unable to create link (name already exists)". I'm working on debugging it, but if you know why that's happening, it would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Ok, it appears to be an overwriting issue. I added a line "f.__delitem__('Log list')" before your last line, and it works. If you add that in there, I'll accept the answer, thanks!